# Undefined variable: students (View: D:\exam\curd\resources\views\home.blade.php) in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

working with laravel 5.7 and need display student table data in the home page, home.blade.php

```
<table class="table">
    <thered>
     <tr>
         <td>Id</td>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td>Address</td>
         <td>Telephone</td>
         <td>Actions</td>
     </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      @foreach ($students as $student)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$student->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$student->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$student->address}}</td>
        <td>{{$student->telephone}}</td>
        <td><a class="button is-outlined" href="">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a class="button is-outlined" href="">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

StudentController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $students = Student::all();

    return view('home');
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('StudentController@index');
```

but got this error msg like this,

> Undefined variable: students (View: D:\exam\curd\resources\views\home.blade.php)

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the students to the view, so in your controller add this instead:

```
return view('home', compact('students'));
```

And your route to this:

```
Route::get('/home', 'StudentController@index'); // if this is your root route
```

Comment: did it but same error here

Comment: @banda that's not possible unless you are not loading the page through that controller method. Check my edit for the route.

Comment: used above route also but not success here, same error here

Comment: Can you try dumping out something in the controller, to make sure that you at least enter there? In your index function try `dd('test');` if this is printed in your browser.

Comment: try with this `public function index()
    {
      dd('test');
        $students = Student::all();
        return view('home')->withStudents($students);
    }` but same error here

Comment: Yes, so the error is because you don't even load the page through that controller method. Can you give me the url that you are trying to access?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/home

Comment: so try the route I've modified above. And make sure you don't have another `/home` route in your routes file.

Comment: fine @nakov now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `$students` variable in view. You can do that by using `compact()` function or there are many other way.

```
public function index()
{
    $students = Student::all();
    return view('home', compact('students'));
}
```

Comment: did it but same error here

Comment: Try to `dd('hit')` in your controller's method. make sure it hit `index()` method.